# <input type="number"> not working in IE10

Tags: html

Although I'm pretty sure this was working yesterday or the day before, `<input type="number" min="0" max="50" step="10" value="0" />`, for example, no longer works in IE10.  I've tested my browser with http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/Forms/Default.html and it's just not working anymore.  Anyone else having this issue?  Or, did it never work?

Comment: It is also does not work in IE 11  http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17313919/

Comment: Newcomers! Please don't answer this question with JavaScript that does not allow non-numeric input. We already have several (thousand) questions regarding that, including [HTML text input allow only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469357/215552), [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/995183/215552), and [How to make HTML input tag only accept numerical values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13952686/215552), among many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't have support for input type="number" but you can use jQueryUI Spinner widget. It is very simple to use and it has many API's that friendly for developers.

Demo of jQuery-UI Spinner:
https://jqueryui.com/spinner/

API of jQuery-UI Spinner
https://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-change

Comment: Similar function as above but not allowing negative and allowing number paste: 

```
        function FilterInput(e) {
            if (isNaN(e.key) &&
                e.key !== 'Backspace' &&
                !(e.key === 'v' && e.ctrlKey === true) &&
                e.key !== 'Tab'
            ) e.preventDefault();
        };
```

Answer (score 25):

Internet Explorer 10 supports the number input. This is evident from a cursory examination of [their documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as well as an attempt to use it within the browser itself. For example, attempting to place a letter in a number input will result in the value being cleared when the control loses focus.

You can also feature-detect support for number by programmatically doing the aforementioned test:

```javascript
// Create the element
var element = document.createElement( "input" );

// Give it the number property and invalid contents
element.type = "number";
element.value = "qwerty";

// Value should be empty
alert( element.value ? "Not Supported" : "Supported" );
```

Run this test: http://jsfiddle.net/VAZwT/

It may very well be that you're equating progressively-enhanced UI (the spinners) with support for the control itself. I've seen this confuse a few people already. *Some* browsers augment supplement the number input with additional controls, but this is not (to my knowledge) a requirement for support.

A few simple tests for `min`, `max`, and `step` on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sDVK4/show/

Comment: The number field e. g. accepts "2werwer" in IE 10/11

Answer (score 17):

**Please prefer [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16092812/1410020) below from `Sampson` as it's more appropriate**

---

IE doesn't have support for input type="number" but you can use a polyfill to make it work.

Here is the solution : http://html5please.com/#number

Comment: Thanks, I guess the polyfill stuff broke (I didn't write it, just debugging), because it was working.  Cheers.

Comment: IE 10 *does* support the number input type, it just not renders it pretty well. You are not seeking for a polyfill but a full fledged spinner control.

Comment: @scravy That's an understatement. It clears non-number values without even telling the user what happened.

Comment: There's currently no polyfill that works properly with Angular.

Answer (score 7):

IE10 does not have Number support. Source: [Can I use ... yet?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)

Just verified on our Windows 8 test machine, there is no number spinner on their test drive site in IE10.

Comment: IE 10 partially supports number input. On putting any non-numeric value it simply clears the input field (supported) but never shows spinner (unsupported)

Comment: In Google Chrome we can not put anything that is not number into the field. In IE and MS Edge putting alpha characters in the field resets the field to 0 on the lost focus and highlights the field in red. This is not a desired behavior, it should be fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has validation bugs/errors still with input type=number, this is in IE11 as well.

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/850187/html5-constraint-validation-is-broken-in-ie11-for-input-type-number

Just as I was starting to like Internet Explorer again... Hopefully they can fix this in IE12, fingers crossed

Comment: They've marked it as resolved in latest Edge release.

Comment: I can not even copy the version info from MS Edge and it took me some time to find the version (It's 25.10586). In any case, the input type="number" does not prevent me from typing any letters. And if letters are typed and I leave the field, it shows 0 instead of the value it had before. I'd rather had it disallow me to type letters.

Comment: The link now redirects to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect .

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I developed, it works pretty well I think, hope it helps someone

```js
function handleKeyPress(e) {
    let newValue = e.target.value + e.key;
    if (
    // It is not a number nor a control key?
    isNaN(newValue) && 
    e.which != 8 && // backspace
    e.which != 17 && // ctrl
    newValue[0] != '-' || // minus
    // It is not a negative value?
    newValue[0] == '-' &&
    isNaN(newValue.slice(1)))
        e.preventDefault(); // Then don't write it!
}
```

```html
Insert a number:
<input onKeyPress="handleKeyPress(event)"/>
```

Comment: Please don't answer this question with JavaScript that does not allow non-numeric input. We already have several (thousand) questions regarding that, including [HTML text input allow only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469357/215552), [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/995183/215552), and [How to make HTML input tag only accept numerical values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13952686/215552), among many others.

Comment: Similar function as above but not allowing negative and allowing number paste: 

```
        function FilterInput(e) {
            if (isNaN(e.key) &&
                e.key !== 'Backspace' &&
                !(e.key === 'v' && e.ctrlKey === true) &&
                e.key !== 'Tab'
            ) e.preventDefault();
        };
```