# HTML5 Input type=Number Polyfill not working in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10, polyfills

I've attempted to use this pollyfill: https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill

But it does nothing in IE10. No script errors either. Is there anything to this besides including the JS and CSS file?

I'll go one step further and point out that the official demo for the polyfill doesn't even work in IE10 on Windows 8: http://jonstipe.github.io/number-polyfill/demo.html

Comment: I guess the polyfill is bugged - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955731/input-type-number-not-working-in-ie10

Answer (score 3):

The problem is evident from the start:

```
i = document.createElement("input");
i.setAttribute("type", "number");
if (i.type === "text")
```

The result of `i.type` in Internet Explorer 10 is "number," meaning Internet Explorer 10 actually supports the number input type — this is further confirmed by [consulting their documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can even confirm that the functionality is in place by trying to put letters into a number input — they'll be removed when the element loses focus.

If you want this tool to progressively enhance the interface for this control in Internet Explorer, you will need to make make the condition resolve to true.

Comment: You're saying IE 10 supports number input types? Why then doesn't it show ths pinner buttons?

Comment: @brushleaf The spinners are an enhancement that some browsers add to the control, but they're not a required UI for the control itself. The number control is defined by its behavior, rather than its presentation.

Comment: Ok, the condition should be changed. But what is a good one for IE ?