# IE10 doesn't support input type=number attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am using input `type=number` attribute.

In chrome it works but in IE10 it doesn't display.

What is the alternative way to fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<input type="number"> not working in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955731/input-type-number-not-working-in-ie10)

Comment: Create own `+` and `-` buttons, place them where you need and after click change the input value. Simply two-line JS.