# HTML5 - type="number" prevents non-numbers in Chrome but not in IE & FF

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm coding a site in MVC and I have a price field in my form.
My Razor code looks like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "myclass", min = 0, max = 1000000 } })
```

and my ViewModel property looks like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Price")]
[Range(0, 1000000, ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid Price")]
public int Price { get; set; }
```

In Chrome the user can't enter any other characters than `.` but in Firefox and Internet Explorer they can, which is not what I want.

Is it correct that HTML5 standards do not extend to the UI? And does Chrome doing a bonus? Or should IE and FF block letters (e.g. characters like `$`) and I have done something wrong?

EDIT: If I begin the input with, say, $ in IE it blanks the control upon losing focus. In Firefox it remains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<input type="number"> not working in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955731/input-type-number-not-working-in-ie10)

Comment: I saw that but wasn't sure it was exactly the same thing as FF is also not behaving as I expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using JQuery. These are the steps:

1) Create an external file to load - MyUtils.js

2) Paste in this JQuery code:

```
// Use like: $('#SomeId').forceNumeric()
jQuery.fn.forceNumeric = function (intsOnly) {
    return this.each(function () {
      $(this).keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey &&
            // numbers   
            key >= 48 && key <= 57 ||
            // Numeric keypad
            key >= 96 && key <= 105 ||
            // Backspace and Tab and Enter
           key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 ||
            // Home and End
           key == 35 || key == 36 ||
            // left and right arrows
           key == 37 || key == 39 ||
            // Del and Ins
           key == 46 || key == 45)
        {
            // ints only: look for a decimal. Disallow comma
            // minus and period on keypad
                if ((intsOnly) && (key == 190 || key == 188 || key == 109 || key == 110)) {
                    return false;
            }
                // Input is OKAY
                return true;
            }
        return false;
         });
    });
}
```

3) On the page you want to use this, load the js file
    e.g. script src="/Scripts/MyUtils.js"

4) Apply the method to the field on setup

```
$('#Price').forceNumeric(true);
```