# <input type="number" /> doesn't show up/down spinner in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

jQuery spinner give me input number with increment and decrement option. Html5 number also does the same thing but not working in IE

Is there any ways to fix this?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Comment: IE and Edge don't support having increment/decrement buttons for input type number. If you want that feature you will have to use a polyfill: https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill

Comment: Am using IE with Edge as default. But didn't seemed to work.

Comment: Thought about number-polyfill but seems to be lot of html for to be added for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.. Just was checking is there any other way to fix this..

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955731/input-type-number-not-working-in-ie10