# Add Quantity Spinner to Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am in the process of working through a tutorial on Angular JS in which we build a shopping cart app.

Adding items to the shopping cart is done through the click of a button. That works fine. However, once I go to view the shopping cart and checkout, I want to have a "spinner" on the quantity so I can increase/decrease the quantity.

I am stuck working with IE 11 and, while it may support the HTML 5 input type "number", it does not augment the control as a spinner ([As seen in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16092812/4215616))

Therefore I am attempting to add a jQuery UI spinner to my partial view.

Here is my main view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sportsStore">
<head>
    <title>SportsStore</title>

    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/Styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/Styles/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="js/ngSportStore.js"></script>
    <script src="routes/sportsStoreRoutes.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
    <script src="filters/customFilters.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/productListControllers.js"></script>
    <script src="components/cart/cart.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/statesController.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/checkoutController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
        <cart-summary></cart-summary>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="data.error">
        Error ({{data.error.status}}). The product data was not loaded.
        <a href="/app.html" class="alert-link">Click here to try again</a>
    </div>

    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my partial view for my cart:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#spinner").spinner({
            min: 0
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Your cart:</h2>

<div ng-controller="cartSummaryController">

    <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="cartData.length === 0">
        There are no products in your cart.

        <a href="#/products" class="alert-link">Click here to continue shopping</a>
    </div>

    <div ng-hide="cartData.length === 0">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in cartData">
                    <td class="text-center"><input id="spinner" class="pull-left" value="{{item.count}}"></td>
                    <td class="text-left">{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{item.price | currency}}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{(item.price * item.count) | currency}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="remove(item.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-right">Total:</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{total() | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/products">Continue shopping</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/placeorder">Place Order</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the partial view, the textbox for quantity is displayed and populated with the value from the model, but the icons for the spinner are not displayed.

I put together this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PStoner3/m2s00q4e/) in which everything works as desired. But I just can't seem to get this to work in my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

> EDIT

I have tried the following suggestions: Add Font-awesome, include and use the latest version of JQuery. Neither have worked. I've tried moving where I load JQuery to the partial view. When I do that and, monitoring IE F12 network, I do not see the libraries being downloaded from the CDN.

In addition, I added an alert to the document.ready function and it is not being fired.

Any other suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Normally those Icons are generated by _font-awesome_. I don't know if it's this way made in JQuery UI but in my experience it is not wrong to load _font-awesome_. Perhaps you wan't to load the newest jQuery (2.2.3).

Comment: Do you have jquery installed or are you relying on the jq-lite that Angular ships with for this?

Comment: @ruby_newbie, yes I do have JQuery loaded. I'm loading it before the angular libraries.

Comment: @Nico I will try out both, loading font-awesome and the latest JQuery and see if that helps.