# HTML5 input type number support in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have JS code for checking number input

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {

    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    // Added to allow decimal, period, or delete
    if ( charCode == 190 || charCode == 46 || charCode == 45 || charCode == 32 || charCode == 43) 
        return true;

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) 
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Html input:

```
<input class="input_txt1" type="text" 
       placeholder="Client Postal Code"         
       onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="ZCHADR5">
```

Now if switch to HTML5, and use input `type=number`, the same is not working in IE .how should  I support it  in IE.

Comment: what is not working in IE?

Comment: Could you specify IE version?

Comment: input type is number, but i can enter characters also.. IE version 11

Comment: I am confused, what it means to support html5 tags in IE, if the tag is not working ,does it mean we have to provide some additional code to make it support or just tell the user , cant provide support in IE

Comment: @MozifBeigh https://modernizr.com/ will help you regarding your issue.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955731/input-type-number-not-working-in-ie10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955731/input-type-number-not-working-in-ie10)

Comment: @MozifBeigh Definitely Yes. [PolyFills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) are created to address this issue, I mean lack of some feature on some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

[PolyFills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) are created to address some browser[Specially IE] issues on supporting some features/tags they don't cover. One for each feature. For example you need HTML5Shiv(shim) to add css3 styling support to IE, Fabric.js for rendering SVG via HTML5 canvas, & etc.

[Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) has aggregated most of them under an all-in-one library.

But after all, even with this in mind, you have 2 options to solve these kinda issues.

1. Fill the shortage of browser on the feature by Polyfills.
2. Stick with JavaScript for fulfilling what you need.

For this particular case, I prefer the latest solution.

I recommend you sticking with [FormValidator](http://www.formvalidator.net/) jQuery Library for a consistent, complete & easy-to-use solution form validation across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

My first observation is that you should try writing unobtrusive JavaScript. This simply means separate HTML from JavaScript.
Secondly, try this method which checks for existence of DOM Level 2 method on the element passed in. If it exists, 
it is used, passing in the event type, event handler function and false (to indicate the bubbling phase). 
If the IE method is available, it is used as a second option. The event type must be prefixed with 'on' in order 
for it to work in IE 8 and earlier. The last resort is to use DOM Level 0 method (code should never reach here in modern browsers).

```
var appEvents = (function() {
    'use strict';
    var instance;

    function init() {

        return {
            addHandler: function(element, type, handler) {
                if (element.addEventListener) {
                    element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
                } else if (element.attachEvent) {
                    element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
                } else {
                    element['on' + type] = handler;
                }
            },
            removeHandler: function(element, type, handler) {
                if (element.removeEventListener) {
                    element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
                } else if (element.detatchEvent) {
                    element.detatchEvent('on' + type, handler);
                } else {
                    element['on' + type] = null;
                }
            },
        };
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function() {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = init();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

var appEventsInstance = appEvents.getInstance();
var input = document.querySelector('#ZCHADR5');
var handler = function(event) {
   // define event
}
// call addHandler
appEventsInstance.addHandler(input, 'onkeypress', handler);
```