# Simple Input with Number

Tags: html

I though I was a good programmer until my team decided to support IE11.

I just want a input that can ONLY have NUMBERS OR FLOATS (12.50, whatever)

Why on earth this doesn't work?

```html
<span>Try to type a letter in IE11. It shouldn't work!!</span>
<input type="number" />
```

ANy help please?

Comment: The duplicate should help... Looking at [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/110895/) it says fixed in Edge. Nothing to do with your programming skills

Comment: also a number *is* a float ...

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955731/input-type-number-not-working-in-ie10

Comment: I think your code is wrong to begin with looking at this question again ... floats don't work in Firefox either - number only supports ints - not floats