# IE 11 not respecting input number and allowing non numeric values to be entered

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

The browser IE 11 is allowing non-numeric values to be entered into a number input. I have tested in other browsers such as Chrome and Firefox and they are respecting the number input.

This image shows how in IE 11 the user can enter a comma and the letters "gal".

[image]

```
<div class>
    <input type="number" min="0" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" class="form-control questTxt" value="">
</div>
```

Is number input not supported in IE 11? This resource appears to show that it does? 
[LINK TO RESOURCE](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-11.html)
[image]

Comment: Nothing in the specification last time I checked stated it is to prevent users from entering invalid characters. It just has to not give you the value if it is invalid.

Comment: When a user fills out the form the values are stored in the DB which allows the data to be stored in the wrong format, I could ideally add some extra validation to prevent this from happening but I would have expected this to be something the browser could handle? @epascarello

Comment: So when you read the .value it has those invalid characters? Are you running in some backwards compat mode?

Comment: That is correct @epascarello when I check the value it has those invalid characters so when it is saved to the DB if there was something entered as "1,450 gal" it is saved to the DB as "1,450 gal" instead of "1450". As previously mentioned I could add some simple regex validation to the value so it is saved without the invalid characters but I thought this could be something handled by the browser? In IE 11 the number input is being treated as a text input.

Comment: So add code to do your own validation if it is not supported.

Comment: Sounds good thanks @epascarello last thing in mind before I go down the road of providing some validation. Any chance of a meta tag that could potentially be the issue for not recognizing the input as number?

Answer (score 0):

As epascarello said, the type attribute is there for validation purposes, so if you enter text into a number field and try to submit a form, it will not let you. I couldn't tell you why that's not default for a *number* input, but browser compatibility has been a pain ever since browsers existed.

If you want to the user to actually be unable to enter anything except for numbers, you can do it in JavaScript.

```
const inputField = document.querySelector("input");

inputField.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
    if (e.which > 31 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IE 11 browser has some issues with Input type Number.

You can refer to the known issues for the IE browser on the [CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) site.

As a workaround, you can use this JS function.

```js
function handleKeyPress(e) {
    let newValue = e.target.value + e.key;
    if (
    // It is not a number nor a control key?
    isNaN(newValue) && 
    e.which != 8 && // backspace
    e.which != 17 && // ctrl
    newValue[0] != '-' || // minus
    // It is not a negative value?
    newValue[0] == '-' &&
    isNaN(newValue.slice(1)))
        e.preventDefault(); // Then don't write it!
}
```

```html
Insert a number:
<input onKeyPress="handleKeyPress(event)"/>
```

Reference:

[input type=“number” not working in IE browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494275/10309381)