# How can I restrict a user to only enter a number in an input field?

Tags: javascript

Trying to limit the user to only enter numbers in a text field.

Comment: You need to use ```number``` input.

Comment: Refer to the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952686/how-to-make-html-input-tag-only-accept-numerical-values

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you're talking about FORM in HTML.
There are several ways to do that:

### Input type

As [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4203289/alexander-popov) proposed, you can set the `input` type to `number`.

For example, in this form the user is required to provide his/her ID number before submitting. Please note that, the `type` is set to `number`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="action_page.php">
    ID Number:<br>
    <input type="number" name="id" value="0">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### Javascript

you can set a javascript function that validates the input on-submit.

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["id"].value;
        if (x == null || x.search(/^\d+$/i) < 0) {
            alert("ID must be a number");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.php"
      onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_validate) is another example on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com)

### AngularJS

There is a lot of buzz around AngularJS and I assume you may want to go there in some point.
Fortunately, the AngularJS documents regard that subject are pretty understandable and straightforward or at least to me.

Here are some examples:

- [Input directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)
- [AngularJS API Ref - input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D)