# Using <input type="text" for calculator input instead of <input type="number"

Tags: html, input

The following is for part of an app that I'm creating.
It actually works perfectly as is except on some particular android phones which display a numeric pad without a minus key.
Tmin is most likely always going to be a minus number.
If I convert all of the inputs to

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body>
        <body STYLE="background-color: #F87217; background-size: cover"></body>
        <br>
            <center>
                <h2 style="font-family:verdana;">Title</h2>
            </center>
            <center>
                <p>Voc + &#x194;v (Tmin - TSTC)M
                </
                <p>
                    <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="amount.value = (a.valueAsNumber + b.valueAsNumber * (d.valueAsNumber - c.valueAsNumber) * e.valueAsNumber) .toFixed(2)">
                        <label for="a">Voc Array</label>
                        <center>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" id="a" name="a">
                            </center>
                            <label for="b">&#x194;v</label>
                            <center>
                                <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" id="b" name="b">
                                </center>
                                <label for="c">Tmin</label>
                                <center>
                                    <input type="number" step="0.001" min="-5.00" id="c" name="c">
                                    </center>
                                    <label for="d">Tstc</label>
                                    <center>
                                        <input type="number" step="0.0001" min="0" id="d" name="d">
                                        </center>
                                        <label for="e">M</label>
                                        <center>
                                            <input type="number" step="0.001" min="0" id="e" name="e">
                                            </center>
                                            <p>
                                                <h3>Total: </h3>
                                                <strong>Volts 
                                                    <output name="amount" step="0.01" min="0" for="a b c d e">0</output>
                                                </strong>
                                            </p>
                                            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                                            </form>
                                        </center>
                                    </link>
```

Comment: And learn more about HTML since `label`s cannot be nested https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element

Answer (score 0):

on the event  onclick' or 'onsubmit' or 'onblur' occur on the submit button,you call a javascript function to convert them to numeric value.

i suggest you to know javascript.

```
 1) how read the value of the DOM element of your input field.
 2)How to remove/(or replace with null) the characters except numbers from variable.(learn about regular expression in string replace/remove)
 3) how to writes the value of variable to teh DOM element (Your's input field)
```

Do that before submit the form.

You can refer this already asked question  from [How to make HTML input tag only accept numerical values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952686/how-to-make-html-input-tag-only-accept-numerical-values)