# Html input type="number" returns empty string as value

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

When you have:

`<input type="number" id="myInput" />`

and you fill in quite some rubbish like:
`8,5,.,.,.,54.,543,.4`

Then `$('#myInput').value` will return `''`
This means that it is treated as if nothing was filled in by the user, messing up my form validation.

How can I retrieve the actual input?

A codePen can be found here, you can check the console that it indeed prints an empty string: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQrrXz?editors=1111

I am on chrome, but on safari this also happens.

I still want to be able to accept normal number inputs, including decimals.

Comment: change type to text ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz how does that solve the problem for type="number" ?

Answer (score 1):

You are putting string into type='number' which is not correct.

You get this error in console when you do it.

> The specified value "8,5,.,.,.,54.,543,.4" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

You can change type='text' instead or put pure number to type='number'

**Example:**

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('myInput').value)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="43.,.,,.,.5" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but of course i can not control my users to not put rubbish in there. I want to get the actual filled in value so i can give proper instructions to tell the user to fix their input. 

Changing it to text is not an option. That removes the extra features you get, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: @WouterWillems then in that case you have to validate the input using js , have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952686/how-to-make-html-input-tag-only-accept-numerical-values